# The rate of decrease

Tags: calculus, integration

A factory has been dumping large quantities of waste into a nearby river. To meet the new government environmental standard, the polluting has
been decreasing.

The rate of decrease is $5e^{−0.4t}$ tons per year, where $t$
is the number of years from 2013 $(t = 0)$. What is the total amount of
waste dumped into the river if the polluting continues indefinitely from
now (2016) according to the formula?

my working:

$∫5e^{−0.4t}$  = $-25/2e^{-2t/5}+c$

after this im not sure what to do i think i have to do the thing $∫^{3}$ and it has a number at the bottom and you subtract one from the other

if you could please help me that would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean how much pollutant is dumped from 2016 to the end of all time.
In this case, it is given by the integral
$$
\int_3^{\infty}\frac{dp}{dt}=5\int_3^{\infty}e^{-.4t}\mathrm dt
$$